# Custom InfoWindow -- image showing, text not showing

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to make an infowindow showing an image, a title, and a subtitle, using the default design for the InfoWindow, and am thereby implementing the InfoWindowAdapter interface in my code. Because I want to keep the default design for the window, I am using the getInfoContents method and setting my values there. However, the only thing that shows when I click on the marker is the image, not the text. I tried commenting out the image to see if the text was just getting buried by the image, but nothing showed up. My Title and subtitle fields are not showing in the callout.

However, when I put the same code inside the getInfoWindow method, all three fields show up as expected.

I'd rather not use the getInfoWindow method since the default callout style suffices for me.

Here's where I call the custom info adapter:

```
 private class CustomWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
    private View infoView;

    CustomWindowAdapter() {
        infoView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_map_infoview, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker)
    {
        TextView title = (TextView)infoView.findViewById(R.id.popup_title);

       TextView subtitle = (TextView)infoView.findViewById(R.id.popup_subtitle);

        ImageView image = (ImageView)infoView.findViewById(R.id.popup_image);

        title.setText(marker.getTitle());
        subtitle.setText(marker.getSnippet());
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);

        return infoView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker)
    {
       return null;
    }
}
```

And here's my layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/popup_image"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/popup_title"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/popup_subtitle"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas of why it might not be showing up?

Comment: Your layout is a bit odd. Shouldn't those children have `wrap_content`, instead of `match_parent`, for their width and height?

Comment: @CommonsWare: And that solved it! Oh dear. I'm quite new to Android and didn't think about that being the reason. Put that as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems with info windows is that since the `View` is being rendered by another process, you cannot readily use tools like Hierarchy View to see if the layout is working as expected. Using an IDE's graphical layout editor can help provide a preview that may be useful in diagnosing problems.

Regardless, in this case, you requested that all three children of a vertical `LinearLayout` have a height of `match_parent`, and with no weight. As a result, "first one in wins", and the two `TextView` widgets would wind up with a height of 0.

Comment: check my gist of info window layout. In preview mode its looks ok but when I run on the device it will show the only image, not the text view. https://gist.github.com/FazalHussain/88c93498876aff1ec64c252fa112a9a6